# Click event for JQuery AJAX not executing

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, express, ejs

I am trying to make a website where the text fields on the pages can be updated via the website. On the 'admin' page of the site, I allow the user to set the field by running an AJAX request when the button is pressed. However, nothing is happening upon pressing the button.

I am using Express.js + E.js + JQuery.

`admin.ejs`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css">
    <title>Manage the website</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitButton").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'updateData',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        text: 'email@example.com',
                        message: 'hello world!'
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>


<header>
    <!-- Put partial includes here -->
</header>

<div class="topPage">


  <h1>Hello, <%= firstName %>!</h1>
<p1>
    Find a value you would like to edit, then press send. The website can take up to 10 mins for the changes to apply. The changes will not change live.
</p1>
</div>

<div class="homepage">
    <div class="information">
        <h1>
            Homepage variables
        </h1>
        <p1>
            Variables for the 'homepage' page are displayed below. Changes can take up to 10 mins to apply globally.
        </p1>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <label>
            Change the 'body' of 'homepage'
        </label>

        <form action="javascript:void(0)">
            <input type="text" id="textField" name="text" value="<%= pageData.get('homepage').homeBody%>" required>
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton">
        </form>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

</script>


</html>
```

I set the action of the form to void to ensure that the page doesn't reload, but I still need the Ajax to work.

In the `website.js` file (where the express app is) I `console.log()` the request body to make sure it is coming through. Nothing is logging.

`website.js`

```js
app.post('/updateData', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

The ajax should run when the form submit button is pressed.

I am kind of new to web development in general so all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: _"I set the action of the form to void to ensure that the page doesn't reload"_  this is usually better done by using `e.preventDefault()` in your click event handler. Or by simply using `<button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>`

Comment: Have you included any request body parsing middleware, ie `app.use(express.urlencoded())`

Comment: @Phil Yes I have. I’ll be sure to change to a simple button tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id="submitButton" shoudl've been a button, not an input. Change the input id tag, and add a button inside that Form and give "submitButton" as ID

hope it helps

Comment: `<input type="submit">` renders as a button

Comment: I changed it to a button, but still nothing is happening when somebody clicks the button.

Comment: Actually, The logging to the console disappeared for some reason! this worked! Thank you both!